# Duplicate static_placeholder makes placeholders uneditable

Tags: python, django, django-cms

My site has a newsbanner which is displayed on every page, thus I have created static_placeholders to manage the content of it. However, the banner has a different look on mobile, which means I've created 2 sections, where one displays the large screen newsbanner and the other section displays the mobile version. The content, however, is the same, so I have duplicated the static_placeholder from the large screen section to the mobile section like this:

```
<div class="section no-padding">
            <div class="row hide-on-large-only hide" id="announcement-mobile" style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #26a69a 0%, #26a69a 50%, #ffffff 50%, #ffffff 100%); ">
                <div class="col s12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-image"><a class="btn-floating btn-flat waves-effect waves-default transparent hide-announcement" href="#!" style=""><i class="material-icons">close</i> </a>
                            {% static_placeholder "CTA billede" %}
                            <span class="card-title"><i class="material-icons">fiber_new</i> {% static_placeholder "CTA overskrift" %}</span></div>
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <p class="teal-text text-lighten-1 left-align">{% static_placeholder "CTA tekst" %}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-action">
                            {% static_placeholder "CTA links" %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end mobile -->
        <div class="section no-padding">
            <div class="row hide-on-med-and-down hide" id="announcement" style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #26a69a 0%, #26a69a 50%, #ffffff 50%, #ffffff 100%); ">
                <div class="col s12 m8 offset-m2">
                    <div class="card horizontal hoverable">
                        <div class="card-image">
                            {% static_placeholder "CTA billede" %}
                        </div>
                    <div class="card-stacked">
                        <a class="btn-floating btn-flat waves-effect waves-default transparent hide-announcement" href="#!"><i class="material-icons blue-grey-text">close</i> </a>
                        <div class="card-content blue-grey-text">
                            <span class="card-title light blue-grey-text"><i class="material-icons small">fiber_new</i>{% static_placeholder "CTA overskrift" %}  </span>
                            <div class="divider blue-grey" style="padding-bottom: 5px; margin-bottom: 15px;"></div>
                            <p class="blue-grey-text left-align">{% static_placeholder "CTA tekst" %}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-action">
                            {% static_placeholder "CTA links" %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- end desktop -->
        </div><!-- End CTA -->
```

This however throws the following error:
[image: Picture of error]

Which results in placeholder becoming uneditable.

python version 3.6.1
Django version 1.10.7
Djangocms version 3.4.4

Comment: What's your question? It does make sense that you can't use the same static placholder twice in a template, doesn't it?

Comment: This is expected behaviour - placeholders need to be unique